How to concatenate two column data into one?
I want to concatenate the data in botanical column into item column. The code below work perfectly in concatenating location column, but l don't know how to apply concatenation for multiple column data.
farmtable



Id
Item
Botanical Name
Location




1
Apple
Malus spp
Block C


2
Coffee
Coffea
Block A


3
Coffee
Coffea
Block B


4
Apple
Malus spp
Block B



SELECT
 Item,
 Botanical,
 STUFF(
     (SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + Location
      FROM farmtable
      WHERE Item = a.Item
      FOR XML PATH (''))
      , 1, 1, '')  AS URLList
FROM farmtable AS a
GROUP BY Item, Botanical

Expected Result



Id
Item
Location




1
Apple, Malus spp
Block C, Block B


2
Coffee, Coffea
Block A, Block B




As you're using Express, why are you not using a fully supported version of SQL Server/ Then you have access to STRING_AGG and then don't need to use the "old" FOR XML PATH "trick". (This isn't even the 1st, 2nd or 3rd time you got this advice).

SQL Server 2014 is no longer in mainstream support and even the extended paid support ends in 3 months. All supported versions have STRING_AGG. Why are you still using 2014?

Alright noted. I will get an improved sql version. Thanks

You can update your code and use CONCAT(Item, ' ', Botanical).

In your query, update SELECT by removing Item, Botanical and use CONCAT(Item, ' ', Botanical).
As mentioned in one of the comment, you can use STRING_AGG.

Here is the complete query.
SELECT
 CONCAT(Item, ' ', Botanical) AS Item,
 STRING_AGG(Location, ',') AS [Location]
FROM farmtable AS a
GROUP BY Item, Botanical



In case you want to stick with STUFF then use CONCAT as mentioned above & update WHERE condition inside STUFF to Item = a.Item AND Botanical = a.Botanical.

Here is the complete query.
SELECT
 CONCAT(Item, ' ', Botanical) AS Item,
 STUFF(
     (SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + Location
      FROM farmtable
      WHERE Item = a.Item AND Botanical = a.Botanical
      FOR XML PATH (''))
      , 1, 1, '')  AS [Location]
FROM farmtable AS a
GROUP BY Item, Botanical


YOu would be much better off with comparing item and Botatical's values separately (what the use of an AND) rather than CONCATenating them (as that isn't SARGable).
